# Doubt about haram thing

Tags: halal-haram

So I cheated in 3 out of 6 subjects in my exam and scored 3.7gpa out of 4. After that I realised this is wrong and repented and promised not to do this again.
Now, I was collecting money for buying a new mobile but couldn't collect enough money.
One night my father and I were sitting and my mom said that don't spend money on unnecessary things and get a mobile. My father said I will buy you a one as I couldn't save enough money.

Now I am having doubt that
he gifted me phone on my result and should I take this because I cheated in exam?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t tell your father you cheated.
Allah concealed your sin and you repented.
If you take the phone as a reward regardless even after repenting, what’s the point of repenting when you really didn’t deserve the phone and sinned? Simply politely decline the offer and next time work harder on your own to do better on your exams and study-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum brother (or sister),

---

Actually, it's hardly possible to inform your father about your cheating. So, I think it will be better to take the gift, put it within any locker instead of using the mobile and simultaneously continue collecting money. When your collected amount will reach the price of the mobile, you can donate it to any mosque on behalf of your father (pray to Allah so that he give the *sawab* to your father instead of you). Then start using the mobile.

Finally, I recommend to ask any *Alim* (such as the *Imam* of your local Mosque) about my procedure and be sure if it is allowed or not.
You can ask in [IslamQA](https://IslamQA.info/en) also.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, go to your father and tell him that you have cheated in exams and after that it is on your father whether he gives you that mobile or not .